# Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Basically I'm trying to create a **gui** for easier file editing.

I have an array like this: (The keys are dynamic so the array does not use a template and I can refer to it's contents.)

[image: console.log output here for the array]

When I'm trying to loop through it gives me an error:

> Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

The error happens on this line in the *multiarray.component.html*:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key][sub]) === 'multiarray'">
  <multiarray-component [key]="sub" [configFile]="configFile" [value]="configFile[key][sub]" [descriptions]=""></multiarray-component>
</ng-template>
```

Code:
*multiarray.component.html*

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h4>{{key}}</h4>

  <div class="row">

    <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(value) !== 'multiarray'">
      <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key]) === 'text' || getType(configFile[key]) === 'number'">
        <input-component [key]="key" [value]="configFile[key]" [descriptions]=""></input-component>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key]) === 'boolean'">
        <checkbox-component [key]="key" [value]="configFile[key]" [descriptions]=""></checkbox-component>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key]) === 'array'">
        <array-component [key]="key" [value]="configFile[key]" [descriptions]=""></array-component>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(value) === 'multiarray'">
      <div *ngFor="let sub of getKeys(value)">

        <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key][sub]) === 'multiarray'">
          <multiarray-component [key]="sub" [configFile]="configFile" [value]="configFile[key][sub]" [descriptions]=""></multiarray-component>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key][sub]) === 'text' || getType(configFile[key][sub]) === 'number'">
          <input-component [key]="sub" [value]="configFile[key][sub]" [descriptions]=""></input-component>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key][sub]) === 'boolean'">
          <checkbox-component [key]="sub" [value]="configFile[key][sub]" [descriptions]=""></checkbox-component>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template [ngIf]="getType(configFile[key][sub]) === 'array'">
          <array-component [key]="sub" [value]="configFile[key][sub]" [descriptions]=""></array-component>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>

  <span *ngFor="let description of descriptions">{{description}}</span>
</div>
```

*multiarray.component.ts*

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'multiarray-component',
  templateUrl: './multiarray.component.html',
  styles: [`
    span {
      display: block;
      font-size: 11px;
    }
  `],
})
export class MultiArrayComponent {
  @Input() key: string;
  @Input() value: object;
  @Input() configFile: object;
  @Input() descriptions: string[];

  getType(obj): string {
    let type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
    switch (type) {
      case "[object String]": {
        return "text";
      }
      case "[object Number]": {
        return "number";
      }
      case "[object Boolean]": {
        return "boolean";
      }
      case "[object Array]": {
        return "array";
      }
      case "[object Null]": {
        return "null";
      }
      case "[object Object]": {
        return "multiarray";
      }
      default:
        return "unknown";
    }
  }

  getKeys(object: object): string[] {
    return Object.keys(object);
  }
}
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed.**
The problem was that I tried to get the data from *configFile[key][sub]* instead of *value[sub]*